# http get android app crashes no result nor error

Tags: java, android, http-get

First of all, i'm pretty new to Java and i'm trying to make an app for home automation.
On the server side I have a PHP script that will toggle my lights, now I would like to send a Get request with android to run the PHP script since that PHP is server side.
Now when i push the button, the app "just" crashes, nothing in the log.

this is my code for the button:

```
Button bA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    bA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                URI Aswitch = new URI("http://192.168.1.186/a-switch.php");
                request.setURI(Aswitch);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "ClientProtocol error");
            } catch(IOException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "IO error");
            } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "URISytax error");
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Check LogCat. Most probably it's a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: post your logcat? we cannot predicts your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    Button bA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    bA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                        URI Aswitch = new URI("http://192.168.1.186/a-switch.php");
                        request.setURI(Aswitch);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "ClientProtocol error");
                    } catch(IOException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "IO error");
                    } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "URISytax error");
                    }

                }
            }).start();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to read the content of an url and If its doesn't match the correct output (Aka i'm outside my Home network) to send the request through a VPN?

Comment: Please put a seprate question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are making this request on the main thread. Use `AsyncTask` to do your networking request.
Also don't forget to add the permission `android.permission.INTERNET` to the manifest file